# How to represent many parts of awk sub/gsub's matched string

Tags: regex, awk, gsub

How to represent more than one part of awk sub or gsub's matched string.

For a regexpr like "##code", if I want to insert a word between "##" and "code", I would want a way like VSCode's syntax in witch $1 represent the first part and $2 represent the second part

```
sub(/(##)(code)/, "$1before$2", str)
```

from awk's user manual, I found that awk use & to represent the whole matched string。 How can I represent one，two or more part in the matched string like VSCode.

> sub(regexp, replacement [, target])
>   Search target, which is treated as a string, for the leftmost, longest substring matched by the regular expression regexp. Modify the entire string by replacing the matched text with replacement. The modified string becomes the new value of target. Return the number of substitutions made (zero or one).
>
> The regexp argument may be either a regexp constant (/…/) or a string constant ("…"). In the latter case, the string is treated as a regexp to be matched. See Computed Regexps for a discussion of the difference between the two forms, and the implications for writing your program correctly.
>
> This function is peculiar because target is not simply used to compute a value, and not just any expression will do—it must be a variable, field, or array element so that sub() can store a modified value there. If this argument is omitted, then the default is to use and alter $0.48 For example:
>
> str = "water, water, everywhere"
>   sub(/at/, "ith", str)
>   sets str to ‘wither, water, everywhere’, by replacing the leftmost longest occurrence of ‘at’ with ‘ith’.
>
> If the special character ‘&’ appears in replacement, it stands for the precise substring that was matched by regexp. (If the regexp can match more than one string, then this precise substring may vary.) For example:
>
> `{ sub(/candidate/, "& and his wife"); print }`
>
> changes the first occurrence of ‘candidate’ to ‘candidate and his wife’ on each input line. Here is another example:

The user manual's link is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Comment: you're looking for `gensub`

Comment: yes! gensub is perfect for my requrements. Thank you, oguz ismail.

Comment: Be aware that `gensub` is a GNU awk extension.

Answer (score 3):

Your best option is to use GNU awk for either of these:

```
$ awk '{$0=gensub(/(##)(code)/,"\\1before\\2",1)} 1' <<<'##code'
##beforecode

$ awk 'match($0,/(##)(code)/,a){$0=a[1] "before" a[2]} 1' <<<'##code'
##beforecode
```

The first one only lets you move text segments around while the 2nd lets you call functions, perform math ops or do anything else on the matching text before moving it around in the original or doing anything else with it:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(##)(code)/,a){$0=length(a[1])*10 "before" toupper(a[2])} 1' <<<'##code'
20beforeCODE
```

After thinking about this for a bit, I don't know how to get the desired behavior in any reasonable way using just POSIX awk constructs. Here's something I tried (the `matches()` function):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    str = "foobar"
    re  = "(f.*o)(b.*r)"
    printf "\nre \"%s\" matching string \"%s\"\n", re, str

    print "succ: gensub():  ", gensub(re,"<\\1> <\\2>",1,str)
    print "succ: match():   ", (match(str,re,a) ? "<" a[1] "> <" a[2] ">" : "")
    print "succ: matches(): ", (matches(str,re,a) ? "<" a[1] "> <" a[2] ">" : "")

    str = "foofoo"
    re  = "(f.*o)(f.*o)"
    printf "\nre \"%s\" matching string \"%s\"\n", re, str

    print "succ: gensub():  ", gensub(re,"<\\1> <\\2>",1,str)
    print "succ: match():   ", (match(str,re,a) ? "<" a[1] "> <" a[2] ">" : "")
    print "fail: matches(): ", (matches(str,re,a) ? "<" a[1] "> <" a[2] ">" : "")
}

function matches(str,re,arr,    start,tgt,n,i,segs) {
    delete arr
    if ( start=match(str,re) ) {
        tgt = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
        n = split(re,segs,/[)(]+/) - 1
        for (i=1; RSTART && (i < n); i++) {
            if ( match(str,segs[i+1]) ) {
                arr[i] = substr(str,RSTART,RLENGTH)
                str = substr(str,RSTART+RLENGTH)
            }
        }
    }
    return start
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk

re "(f.*o)(b.*r)" matching string "foobar"
succ: gensub():   <foo> <bar>
succ: match():    <foo> <bar>
succ: matches():  <foo> <bar>

re "(f.*o)(f.*o)" matching string "foofoo"
succ: gensub():   <foo> <foo>
succ: match():    <foo> <foo>
fail: matches():  <foofoo> <>
```

but of course that doesn't work for the 2nd case as the first RE segment of `f.*o` matches the whole string `foofoo` and of course the same thing happens if you try to take the RE segments in reverse. I also considered getting the RE segments like above but then build up a new string one char at a time from the string passed in and compare the first RE segment to THAT until it matches as THAT would be the shortest matching string to the RE segment BUT that would fail for a string+RE like:

```
str='foooobar'
re='(f.*o)(b.*r)'
```

since `f.*o` would match `foo` with that alorigthm when it really needs to match `fooooo`.

So - I guess you'd need to keep iterating (being careful of what direction you iterate in - from the end is correct I expect) till you get the string split up into segments that each match every RE segment in a left-most-longest fashion. Seems like a lot of work!

Answer (score 0):

When you use GNU awk, you can use `gensub` for this purpose. Without `gensub` for any generic awk it becomes a bit more tedious. The procedure could be something like this:

```
ere="(ere1)(ere2)"
match(str,ere)
tmp=substr(str,RSTART,RLENGTH)
match(tmp,"ere1"); part1=substr(tmp,RSTART,RLENGTH)
part2=substr(tmp,RLENGTH)
sub(ere,part1 "before" part2,str)
```

The problem with this is that it will not always work and you have to engineer it a bit. A simple fail can be created due to the greedyness of the ERE":

```
str="foocode"
ere="(f.*o)(code)"
match(str,ere)                    # finds "foocode"
tmp=substr(str,RSTART,RLENGTH)    # tmp <: "foocode"
match(tmp,"(f.*o)");              # greedy "fooco"
part1=substr(tmp,RSTART,RLENGTH)  # part1 <: "fooco"
part2=substr(tmp,RLENGTH)         # part2 <: "de"
sub(ere,part1 "before" part2,str) # :> "foocobeforede
```